# Поддержка русских букв в границах слов в регулярных выражениях JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения

Написал небольшой код:

```
var a = "температура, температуры, температуров, температур, температурой"; /*текст*/
var b = "температур"; /*что заменяем*/
a.replace(new RegExp(b, 'g'),"осадок"); /*на что заменяем*/
```

В результате получил такой ответ:

```
осадока, осадокы, осадоков, осадок, осадокой
```

Как делать так, чтобы заменились только то, что мы указали?

Comment: Чтобы окончание тоже уходило?

Comment: Чтобы заменились только "температур", а слова с окончаниями: "температура", "температуры" и прочие остались как есть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как границы слова `\b` работают только с буквами из набора ASCII, необходимо использовать "пользовательскую реализацию".

Например, используя новый ECMAScript 2018, можно реализовать границу слова с помощью блоков предварительного просмотра `(?<![\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}_])` и `(?![\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}_])` и флага-модификатора `u`.

Следующий пример кода работает в Chrome, Opera, Node.js, но, к сожалению, не сработает в FireFox и IE:

```js
let a = "температура, температуры, температуров, температур, температурой"; /*текст*/
const b = "температур";
const reg = new RegExp(String.raw`(?<![\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}_])${b}(?![\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}_])`, 'gu');
console.log(a.replace(reg,"осадок"));
```

Можно использовать упрощённый подход: "добавить" в `\w` (=`[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) русские буквы => `[a-zA-Z0-9а-яА-ЯёЁ_]`, тогда получится следующий пример, который сработает во всех браузерах и средах:

```js
var a = "температура, температуры, температуров, температур, температурой"; /*текст*/
var b = "температур";
var reg = new RegExp('(^|[^a-zA-Z0-9а-яА-ЯёЁ_])' + b + '(?![a-zA-Z0-9а-яА-ЯёЁ_])', 'g');
console.log(a.replace(reg,"$1осадок"));
```